# MariaDB unable to get rid of blank password

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

I just bought a VPS and installed MariaDB on it, here's the -version:
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.28-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

So here's the thing. I want to change the `root` user password for my MySQL connection.
I tried almost all the guides on the internet, but I'm still able to connect directly to the database using the command `mysql` without specifying root or password. I'm trying everything as the `root` shell user, if that's a concern.

I've set the `authentication_string` and `password` columns using `PASSWORD()` method, and I confirm that they have encrypted values now. 
I have restarted the MySQL service using `service mysql restart` as well, still all in vain. My port for MySQL is defaulted to `3306`.
What am I missing here? TIA.
(Please don't mark this as duplicate, I've been through almost all posts and tried the solutions, I just need a deeper insight here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently using MariaDB 10.0 packages provided by Debian. Recently Debian switched to using [unix_socket](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/) authentication by default for local root in their packages. You can see it by running

```
SELECT user, host, password, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

If you don't want it, you can switch back to the password authentication by running

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '' WHERE user = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: You're an angel! I literally spent 3 hours to get this to work until I gave up! Quick question, is it possible to enable both authentication?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you have in mind. Obviously, the authentication is configured per user -- you can have the local `root` authenticated via `unix_socket` plugin, and create another super-user which would have the usual password-based access. If you mean whether `unix_socket` can be configured to fallback to password if initial authentication fails -- no, it currently can't do that. You might also want to explore [pam authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pam-authentication-plugin/) -- it is trickier to configure, but if you get through it, it can give you more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, I like the new user idea, and I guess that's all the flexibility I need :)